# Probability of Independent Events Happening at least twice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If the probability of hitting a target is $1/5$ and ten shots are fired independently, what
is the probability of the target being hit at least twice?

Would it be

$$1 - \left[\left(\frac 1 5\right)^{10} + \left(\frac 1 5\right)^{10} \cdot {10 \choose 1}\right]$$

Thanks.

Comment: Not quite. You want to get $1$ minus the probability that you hit a target once or you don't hit any targets. Remember that the probability you **miss** is $\frac{4}{5}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**:

Use $P(X\geq2)=1-P(X<2)$

$$ = 1- \binom{10}{0} (0.2)^{0} (0.8)^{10}-\binom{10}{1} (0.2)^{1}(0.8)^{9}$$

Answer (score 1):

The strategy is good, there are problems of detail. The probability of missing is $\dfrac{4}{5}$. So the probability of missing $10$ times in a row is
$$\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{10}.$$

The probability of hitting exactly once is 
$$\binom{10}{1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^1 \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^9.$$